# Linux stops at "Switched to clocksource tsc" after fresh install of 14.04 -- Setup or reinstall?

Tags: boot, kernel, 14.04

I've been looking forward to installing the latest greatest daily build of Ubuntu 14.04 into my 'new' X301 Lenovo, which seemed promising as the OS preview from live USB worked rather well.

Unfortunately, the bootloading got stuck and after using `recovery mode` boot option, I got this:[image: Booting and all signs of work stop after "Switching to clocksource tsc"] Where booting and all signs of work stop after "Switching to clocksource tsc" -- the OS just hangs so.

I tried editing the Grub command, namely the `linux` line, as suggested at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1184419#p1184419 and a few more tweeks, then lost the naive hopes and came to ask here -- Is there any way to use the latest version of Ubutnu distro on my machine? What would you suggest for my case?